# Setting up multiple IPv6 routes over a single interface on Linux

Tags: ipv6, iproute2, dhcpv6, systemd-networkd

**tldr;** A LAN device is able to get 2 separate internet connection (1 NATted from ISP Router, 1 from manual PPP connection). Able to separate ISP-WAN and PPP-WAN IPv4 into 2 routes using `ip rules` but not IPv6.

---

Apologies for the lengthy post.
My requirement is to have 2 separate routing tables to connect to the internet through 2 separate routes.

I will be sharing how I am managing this with IPv4 - however IPv6 is where I am unable to figure out the steps.

I have a rather unique setup where I am able to get a global IPv6 address from my ISP in 2 ways.
My ISP provides an FTTH modem+router (`RT`) that uses PPPoE to connect to internet.

My LAN is on `192.168.5.0/24` and the ISP `RT` is the default Gateway at `192.168.5.1`

I have a raspberry Pi `RPi` connected to `RT` using single interface `br0` at IP `192.168.5.22` which is where I am performing this setup.

`RT` has an option to enable `PPPoE passthrough` that lets my Raspberry Pi *also* request for a PPP connection and hence,

1 - I can get a public IP on `ppp0` for direct Internet access
2 - I can also access the internet through gateway `192.168.5.1` of `RT`

---

**Working IPv4 Setup**

```
<WAN1> <WAN2>
    |    |
    |    `-RT - <PPP Public IP 1>
    |      `-br_lan - 192.168.5.1/24
    |        `-Laptop
    |          `-eth0 - 192.168.5.100/24 (default gateway: 192.168.5.1)
    |        `-RPi 
    |          `-eth0 - 192.168.5.22/24 (default gateway: 192.168.5.1 in table 111)
    `------------`-ppp0 - <PPP PUBLIC IP 2> (default gateway in table `main`)
```

`ppp0` interface is the default gateway on `RPi`'s main routing table:

```bash
# ip route show
default dev ppp0 scope link
192.168.5.0/24 dev br0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.5.22 metric 204
<redacted hop ip> dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src <redacted PPP-WAN ip>
```

A new separate routing table contains the route to ISP-WAN with `RT` as gateway

```bash
# ip route show table 111
default via 192.168.5.1 dev br0 proto static
192.168.5.0/24 dev br0 proto static
```

A rule is set for all incoming connections from LAN to use ISP-WAN gateway

```bash
# ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
0:      from 192.168.5.0/24 lookup 111
```

### `curl -4 ifconfig.co` from `RPi` does return PPP-WAN public IP ✅
Any device on LAN using `RPi` as gateway gets the ISP-WAN public IP ✅

All traffic originating from Pi will use `ppp0` and if needed I can add new rules to use ISP-WAN for any VPN interfaces :)
The corresponding systemd-networkd config:

```ini
# cat 11-br0.network
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
#DHCP=ipv6
DHCP=no
Address=192.168.5.22/24
Address=fdXX:22/64
DNS=1.1.1.1
#IPv6AcceptRA=yes
#IPv6PrivacyExtensions=true
IPv6AcceptRA=no

# Seperate LAN and PPP traffic in different tables
[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Gateway=192.168.5.1
Table=111

[Route]
Destination=192.168.5.0/24
Table=111

[RoutingPolicyRule]
From=192.168.5.0/24
Table=111

[Link]
MACAddress=HH:MM:XX:YY:ZZ
```

### The IPv6 part

There are 2 ways I can get IPv6 Access on `RPi`:
**1. Through DHCPv6 requests on `ppp0` with help of `wide-dhcpv6-client.service` ([Ask Ubuntu link that describes this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56890/ipv6-over-pppoe))**
`/etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6c.conf`:

```bash
# Default dhpc6c configuration: it assumes the address is autoconfigured using
# router advertisements.

profile default
{
  information-only;

  request domain-name-servers;
  request domain-name;

  script "/etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6c-script";
};

interface ppp0 {
    # Request Prefix Delegation on ppp0, and give the received prefix id 0
    send ia-pd 0;
};

id-assoc pd 0 {
    prefix-interface br0 {
        # Assign subnet 1 to br0
        sla-len 0;
        sla-id 1;
        ifid-random;
    };
};
```

Resulting ip addr & routing table:

```bash
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.5.22/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
#Global Public
    inet6 2401::XX/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
#ULA
    inet6 fdXX::Y/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
#Link local
    inet6 fe80::Y/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

5: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1492 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 3
    link/ppp
    inet <Public IPv4> peer <IPv4>/32 scope global ppp0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::<ppp0 link local> peer fe80::123:46ff:fe07:0508/128 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# Route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
<PPP IPv6 Prefix>::/64 dev br0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fdXX:22::/64 dev br0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::123:46ff:fe07:0508 dev ppp0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::<ppp0 link local> dev ppp0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev br0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::123:46ff:fe07:0508 dev ppp0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1616sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
```

With this, anything from or through `RPi` (like VPN clients) will  go out through `ppp0` using the WAN prefix provided by `PPP`

**2. Through `RT`'s Router Advertisements on `br0` using following change in `[Network]`:**

```ini
# /etc/systemd/network/11-br0.network
[Network]
DHCP=ipv6
DNS=1.1.1.1
IPv6AcceptRA=yes
IPv6PrivacyExtensions=true
```

With this, all traffic from LAN as well as `RPi` both will use `RT`'s `ISP-WANv6` prefix.

### The problem

If I enable any of the 2 methods, I cannot enable the other.
If I am using ISP-WAN, and I try to get an IPv6 from `ppp0`, `wide-dhcpv6-client.service` will throw `client6_init: bind: Address already in use`.

I tried to setup separate routing table for LAN `br0` by a rule that routes all traffic from `RT`'s ULA use the new table:

```ini
# Setting a static ULA + using DHCP to get Prefix from `RT`
[Network]
DHCP=ipv6
Address=fdZZ::1/64
IPv6AcceptRA=yes
IPv6PrivacyExtensions=true

# Route all outgoing traffic through the gateway provided by RT's RA
[Route]
Destination=::/0
Gateway=_ipv6ra
Table=111

# All traffic to LAN devices that use RT's ULA 
[Route]
Destination=fdXX::/64
Table=111

# All LAN devices (which use RT's ULA) will use the above routes configured in table 111
[RoutingPolicyRule]
From=fdXX::/64
Table=111
```

Other than the link local address `fe80::` I don't get which address is in use.
Tried removing teh link-local address from br0 but no luck.

The Global Prefix from ISP-WANv6 and `ppp0` are both different, The ULA Prefix from `RT` is also different than the static ULA I configured manually.

In IPv4 I can easily create a separate route with a different default gateway, but unable to figure the equivalent in IPv6.

I'd need to be able to have 2 paths to the IPv6 internet, albeit using separate tables
And a rule that tells which route to take based on the originating source.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Since I am not sure this is the right place (I am not actually performing any server level stuff) I will be reposting this in Superuser and any solution I find there will be commented here too

Comment: Why are you using ULA? That is for traffic you never want to go to the public Internet. IPv6 has enough Global addressing for every device to have a Global address. IPv6 routers send out RAs that tell hosts which gateway to use for routes, and the gateway is the router's Link-Local address. All IPv6 interfaces will have a Link-Local address. You should also read and understand _[RFC 6724, Default Address Selection for Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6724.html)_.